# Is it possible to automate creating pull requests to another repo using Github API and Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Let's say I have a repo A, and whenever I merge some new changes, I want to automatically create a new PR to change one file in repo B that reports the changes I have made.

For example, I add a new package to my package.json in repo A, and upon merge, I want to automatically create a new PR to change all_packages.txt in repo B to report my change. Is this possible with Github API and Actions?

To my understanding, I can fork repo B, create new branches, commit changes to it then create pull requests, but is it possible to do all of this while only changing repo A, without ever touching repo B?

Comment: As long as you can provide a personal access token with write permissions on repo B, you can do that from a workflow that runs in repo A.